# “all that” vs. “all what”

Tags: word-choice, relative-clauses, what-that

I’ve heard somebody say:

> All what is needed is …

I thought the correct way to phrase it was:

> All that is needed is …

However, thinking about it more, the former doesn’t sound *too* incorrect, albeit a bit odd. Is the former grammatically correct? Am I alone in thinking the latter sounds more natural?

Comment: possibly related: [When is it appropriate to use 'that' as opposed to 'which'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-that-as-opposed-to-which), [Is the expression “showed it what for” or “showed it one for”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/31625/8732), [Is “wot wot” or “what-what” an authentic British expression?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/14369/8732)

Answer (score 6):

I'd say *all what is needed* is at best semi-literate. True, Google Books give [over 50,000 written instances](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22all%20what%20is%20needed%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en), but probably most of them are "accidental collocations" (e.g. - a sentence ending with the word *"all"*, followed by one starting with *"What is needed"*). Also note that this contrasts with well [over 3 million instances](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22all%20that%20is%20needed%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) of *all that is needed*.

Comment: Interestingly, using *wat* instead of *dat* has the same illiterate connotation in Dutch in many cases, though it is slightly more acceptable in Dutch.

Comment: @Cerberus: The vagaries of what's "acceptable" are tricky to pin down. A year ago I used to cringe if I saw a comment like "**What Cerberus said**" - but I do it myself now, and I've actually become quite fond of the form (you be sure and post another comment somewhere that I can wholeheartedly endorse, just so I can get my rocks off! :)

Comment: Heh, but why did "what Cerberus said" trouble you so much? The problem outlined above is entirely absent from this construction.

Comment: @Cerberus: Yeah, I know the *constructions* are different. But they do both involve the word *"what"* - all I'm saying is whereas I still think OP's one sounds "illiterate", the other one has somehow "grown on me" over the past 12 months.

Comment: You'd better lie *very* still if you want this one to grown on you, what with the ungrammaticality.

Answer (score 5):

In some dialects of English,  'what' is used instead of 'that' as a generic relative clause.

> The car what I saw this morning...

is non-standard but works in (I can't find a reference but Estuary or Cockney sounds right to me).

> All what is needed...

may be a similar usage of 'what' instead  of 'that' for that person's dialect.

Comment: Someone in Eastend London once told me _You speak better English than what I do_ - this is a true story

Answer (score 1):

If written as *All wot is needed*, I could pass it off as dialectic, but in modern English *all that* is far more common.

*All which* seems to be right out.

Comment: I'm surprised to find that [all which is needed](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+which+is+needed&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) occurs at all - it sounds pretty odd to me. But I note that according to NGram it's four times less common than even *"what"*, and prevalence has massively declined since its heyday a century ago, so I'm not going to worry that I'm out of touch with modern usage! :)

Answer (score 1):

'All what is needed' = 'All that which is needed', substituting [ *what* with *that which* ].

Not necessarily ungrammatical nor odd usage. Could be uncommon, though.

Answer (score 1):

It appears, on the whole, to be an archaic usage, but here’s an OED citation from 2007:

> The Riemann tensor tells us all what we need to know about the
>   intrinsic curvature and thus gravity.

Practical advice might well be to use *all that*, but if you want to use *all what*, then there are many precedents.

**EDIT:**

The OED’s definition 7 of *what* is ‘As simple relative (sing. or pl.): Which (or who); that.’  Within that, the first sub-category reads:

> a. referring to a pronoun (demonstrative or indefinite), occasionally
>   to a noun; originally introducing an indirect question in apposition
>   to it  especially, in later use only, in **all what** (now dialect or
>   vulgar).

There are 14 supporting citations under this entry. There are others elsewhere in the OED illustrating *all what*, including one from ‘Timon of Athens’.

Comment: In your example, "us all" means "all of us". So in your example, "all" relates to "us" rather than "what".

Comment: @MetaEd: How do you know?

Comment: That's a really good question. I don't, absolutely, but interpreting language is not objective. Part of what it means to understand language is to apply something sometimes called the "cooperative principle" or the "principle of charity". Applied to this sentence, it means that if there are two ways to read the sentence, and one is grammatically incorrect and the other is grammatically correct, then in the absence of contradictory information one would read it the grammatically correct way. And this occurs automatically.

Comment: @MετάEd: I was intrigued, so I Googled ["tells us all what we need to know"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22tells+us+all+what+we+need+to+know%22&oq=%22tells+us+all+what+we+need+to+know%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l3j62.1858&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). A putative *About 1,660,000 results* actually petered out at just 40, but I had the impression every single one was "grammatical" (i.e. - they meant *tells **all of us** what we need to know*). Google claims *About 5,290,000 results* for *"tells us all **that** we need to know"*, and I'm quite prepared to believe that guess.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I, too, have conducted further research. See my edit.

Answer (score -3):

A very basic but easy way to understand is:  "What" relates to asking a question and "That" relates to making a statment.

So in "All what is needed....." you are asking one or all the questions "what is needed?, Is this all?, Are all these .......... that is needed for......?"

In "All that is needed..." your making the statment "All of this is needed ........" or "All of these........are needed for......."

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: That is not the sense that _what_ is used in here. This is the relative _what_, not the interrogative _what_. Moreover, the explanation (?) you make for either makes very little sense and is more or less impossible to follow.