# 'All that' vs 'all what'

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, differences, pronouns, what-that

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“all that” vs. “all what”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54566/all-that-vs-all-what)

How can I be sure when to use 'all that' or 'all what' in making sentences. Is there any differences in their meaning. I've tried googling but the results just didn't match. For instance:

> All that the president said was published in the dailies.

or

> All what the president said was published in the dailies.

Comment: I think the first sentence is fine and the second is missing an *of* between *all* and *what*

Answer (score 3):

In your examples, the only correct one is the first:

> All that the president said was published in the dailies.

*What* would be correct by itself, as in:

> What the president said was published in the dailies.

However, *all what* is always wrong, and you should use either *all that* (or *everything that*, *the words that*, etc) or *what*.

*That* is a [relative pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_pronoun) like *who/whom*, whereas *what* is a [nominal relative pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses#Nominal_relative_clauses).  The two words fulfill distinct grammatical parts, and cannot be interchanged.

Comment: why is it so? Why can't it be the other way round?

Comment: *What* and *that* have different definitions of usage.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion stems from the fact that *that* is usually a relative pronoun, but it is not so here.  *All that the President said*  would be correct, but only as a longer form of *All the President said* in which *that* is used as a conjunction: consider *All the stuff that the President said*. 
 ?*All that stuff that the President said*  is not ungramnatical, but I doubt whether a native speaker would use it, precisely because of the repetition.

On the other hand, ?*All of what the President said* could only be used (if at all) as an emphatic form of *What the President said*, where *what* really is the relative pronoun.